# My cat is scared of my grandkids?

Tags: cats, behavior, fear, children

My cat literally pooped himself because he's terrified of my grandkids and a flotation device he saw in their wading pool. He never does this, he just started when they came to visit. They have visited before but not for this long of a time. They go home in 3 days.

Their ages are 13,10,7,& 6. He really freaked out with the flotation device. But he pooped on the floor and on the rug.

Could it be the noisiness? The kids? Both?

Answer (score 4):

**Give Your Cat an Escape**

If your cat is not used to children it should be expected that the stomping around and shouting may be frightening to it. I would suggest making a room for the cat a 'No Kid Zone' such that the cat has some place to go where the kids will not follow. Ideally this area would contain their litter box so that you can hopefully avoid more accidents. If your cat is used to spending time with you alone, it would probably be nice to visit them in their preferred area as well so that they don't feel the need to be around the kids when they want attention from you.

Answer (score 1):

The pooping thing could be due to the continued stress he was having by having the kids stay for days. Of course the noises and jumping all around are probably affecting him. Teaching the kids to respect the cat's space is the best you could do for him. Because even if you put your cat in a different room he will still feel that his territory is decreased because of the kids. Although it may comfort him a little. And for the flotation divice it's better to remove it if it was in your pool. If it's in their pool just try to not let your cat a way to come and see it.